# Como reconocer una contraseña del JPasswordField

Tags: java

Estoy varado en un codigo

Tengo una interfaz grafica con un JPasswordField y lo que quiero es que al presionar el botón y la contraseña ingresada es="agente07", me despliegue un JOptionPane diciendo contraseña correcta pero este siempre me despliega contraseña incorrecta.

```
private void btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    
     String contraseña = "";
     char[] password = fieldP.getPassword();
     for(int x=0; x < password.length; x++){ 
         contraseña += password[x];
     }
     if(evt.getSource() == btn){       
         if(contraseña == "agente07"){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanel1, "contraseña correcta: " + contraseña);
         }else {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanel1, "contraseña incorrecta: " + contraseña);
         }        
     }       
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A ver, te voy a poner el código total de un programa en java swing que pide usuario y contraseña y luego si son correctas o incorrectas nos muestra un mensaje. Fíajte que empleo el método de comparación equals

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class UserPassJavaSwing extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //creamos las variables necesarias
    private JPasswordField jpf;
    private JTextField jtf;
    private JButton jb;
    private String name = "", pass = "";
    private char getpass[];

    UserPassJavaSwing()
    {
        //ponemos título al formulario
        setTitle("Usuario y Contraseña");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //llamamos a los métodos
        setJTextFieldandJPasswordField();
        setAction();
        //dimensiones
        setSize(700, 200);
        //lo hacemos visible
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void setJTextFieldandJPasswordField()
    {
        //label usuario
        JLabel usuario = new JLabel("Usuario");
        jtf = new JTextField(10);
        //label contraseña
        JLabel     password = new JLabel("Contraseña");
        jpf = new JPasswordField(10);
        //botón entrar
        jb = new JButton("Entrar");
        /creamos un label chuleta para saber lo que hay que meter como usuario y contraseña
        JLabel UsuarioPass = new JLabel("Usuario  :  JamesBond    Password  :  agente07");
        //lo agregamos todo al panel
        add(usuario);
        add(jtf);
        add(password);
        add(jpf);
        add(jb);
        add(UsuarioPass);
    }

    private void setAction()
    {
        jb.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve)
    {
        //tomamos el texto de las cajas de texto usuario y contraseña
        name = jtf.getText();
        getpass = jpf.getPassword();
        pass = String.valueOf(getpass);
 
        //validamos que los textos coincidan
        if(name.equals("JamesBond") && pass.equals("agente07"))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Usuario y Contraseña orrectos");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecto");
    }
}
```

Y ahora el método main en la clase principal

```
public class UserPassJavaSwingMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //instancioamos la clase userpass....  
        UserPassJavaSwing frame = new UserPassJavaSwing();
    }
}
```

Comment: no se porque no se me ocurrió usar el método equals() gracias